# Does a merge conflict occur everytime same files are changed?

Tags: git

Suppose you have two branches in your git repository and both branches change the same file. Now you merge one branch into the other. My question is, whether there always be a merge conflict even if the lines of the changes are totally different.

Comment: A conflict appears when the two branches modify the same line in different ways. Git is able to solve the situation (and it does not report a conflict) when the line is modified the same way on the two branches. A conflict also occurs when one branch modifies line "n" and the other modifies line "n-1" or "n+1" (the two branches do not modify the same line but Git uses two lines of context for each block of modified lines and cannot rely on them if they are changed on the other branch).

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @matt i tried, thats why i actually wrote this post. I merged a file with line 1,2,4 with new line in 3 and there was a conflict

Comment: Yes, that one is a conflict. But it is easy to make one that is not a conflict, and one counterexample disproves the hypothesis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Git will try to merge the changes, a conflict is raised when the git cannot decide which change to pick over the other - In most cases this happens when two people have changed the same lines in a file.

Also, a merge can enter a conflicted state at two separate points

- Git will fail to merge when it can pre-detect the conflict before the merge starts.  This happens when there are changes either the working directory or staging area of the current project.
- Git will fail during the merge process when there is a conflict between current local branch and the branch being merged.  In most cases the reason behind this  will be the conflict with another developers code

You can read more about this [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts)